# Installed Django app (registration) not using main urls.py for tests

Tags: django, django-urls, django-registration, django-testing

I'm not sure if this is a bug with django-registration or what I'm doing.

I have a bare minimum project, with django-registration installed and no apps of my own. Django-registration requires a few templates, so I have them in `templates/registration`. In each template, I have a template tag `{% url index %}`, which is included in my `urls.py`.

By running `./manage.py test registration --failfast`, I get:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

My own template isn't seeing my url entry.

I debugged into Django's reverse function, and it seems as though my `urls.py` isn't being used at all. Instead `registration.tests.urls.py` is used.

Is this the intended behavior? I'm hoping not, since I can't get basic tests to pass. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in django-registration. [This blog article](http://recursive-design.com/blog/2009/11/10/noreversematch-custom-registration-templates-break-django-unit-tests/) describes the problem and a workaround.